# Detecting multiple presses of the same button

Tags: input-device

I'd like to detect multiple presses of the same button and interpret that differently, for example "tap" means to do function A and "tap-tap" means to do function B.

I've been doing some googling but haven't yet come across a detailed solution for this. I'm sure I can figure out an algorithm/implementation from scratch if I need to, but I'd rather not re-invent the wheel. Ideally this would be implemented in NodeJS, but I can translate the concepts from another language if need be.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution I came up with:

```
'use strict'

const Gpio = require('pigpio').Gpio

class PushButton extends Gpio {

    constructor(gpioPin, double_tap_interval_ms = 400) {
        super(gpioPin, {
            mode: Gpio.INPUT,
            pullUpDown: Gpio.PUD_DOWN,
            edge: Gpio.FALLING_EDGE,            
            alert: true
        });
        this.glitchFilter(10000)
        this.double_tap_interval_ms = double_tap_interval_ms
        this.previous_tap_tick = 0
        this.double_tap_timeout = undefined

        this.on('alert', (level, tick) => {
            if (level == 1) {
                if (this.previous_tap_tick == 0) {
                    // This prevents the math below from screwing up the 
                    // difference check on the first execution
                    this.previous_tap_tick = tick - (this.double_tap_interval_ms * 1000) - 1
                }

                // This difference uses the JavaScript sign propagating right shift 
                // operator to prevent subtraction errors when the tick wraps around.
                // See https://github.com/fivdi/pigpio/blob/master/doc/gpio.md#event-alert
                // for more info.

                let difference = ((tick >> 0) - (this.previous_tap_tick >> 0))
                if (difference / 1000 < this.double_tap_interval_ms) {
                    clearTimeout(this.double_tap_timeout)
                    this.emit('double-tap')
                }
                else {
                    this.double_tap_timeout = setTimeout(() => {
                        this.emit('single-tap')
                    }, this.double_tap_interval_ms)
                    this.previous_tap_tick = tick
                }
            }
        })
    }
}

module.exports = PushButton


// For example:

let b = new PushButton(24)
b.on('single-tap', ()=> {
    console.log('caught single-tap')
})

b.on('double-tap', ()=> {
    console.log('caught double-tap')
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Look-up "state machine" concept.